# T-SQL: select date range from last Friday at 1230pm until Monday at 330am

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, time

I'm creating a query in SQL Server 2008, for an SSRS report that runs every Monday at 0330am, retrieving weekend sales details.

The report is ready, but I had to hard-code the date range, as I'm having trouble expressing that condition in the WHERE statement.

I need to retrieve data based on column `[salestime]` (of type `datetime`), between Friday at 1230pm and Monday at 330am.

I'd really appreciate your assistance with this.

Comment: How does the report run? As in if I run it this wee should it display data only between this Friday 1230pm to Monday 0330am or should it display for all week recrods between the periods?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
WHERE SalesTime BETWEEN DATEADD(HH,-63,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

I believe the time values are 63 hours apart. This is if your report automatically runs at 3:30 AM, which is what it sounds like in your post.

Comment: Thank you! This works great! I will however, be going with the below suggestion, as it will also allow me to leave the report for the sales team to run it at any time throughout the week.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your report *any time during the week* to report on last weekend's sale

```
SET DATEFIRST 7

DECLARE @ThisMonday     date        = DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
DECLARE @LastFriday     date        = DATEADD(DAY, -3, @ThisMonday)

DECLARE @StartTime      datetime    = CAST(@LastFriday AS datetime) + CAST('12:30' AS datetime)
DECLARE @EndTime        datetime    = CAST(@ThisMonday AS datetime) + CAST('03:30' AS datetime)

SELECT  @ThisMonday, @LastFriday, @StartTime, @EndTime
```

Now you can filter your report with `salestime BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime`.